# Flutter: floating modal sheet

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is there a widget that is kind of like the `Modal` `BottomSheet()` where you call using the  `showModalBottomSheet` function, but instead it is not sticking at the bottom but floating in the middle of the screen? like an alert dialog but you can add textField into it.

Comment: Check out [ask] to improve this question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean [SimpleDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SimpleDialog-class.html)?

```
SimpleDialog(
  title: Text('Choose food'),
  children:[
    SimpleDialogOption(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context, "Pizza"); },
      child: const Text('Pizza'),
    ),
    SimpleDialogOption(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context, "Burger");
      },
      child: const Text('Burger'),
    ),
  ],
  elevation: 10,
  //backgroundColor: Colors.green,
)
```